# why Call to undefined method Srmklive\PayPal\Services\PayPal::setExpressCheckout()

Tags: laravel, paypal-sandbox

i try implement the paypal pay on my project, i using the srmklive/paypal v3 and and stamen giving this error

```
Call to undefined method Srmklive\PayPal\Services\PayPal::setExpressCheckout()

use Srmklive\PayPal\Services\PayPal as PayPalClient;
    $provider = new PayPalClient;
        $response = $provider->setExpressCheckout($data);
        $response = $provider->setExpressCheckout($data, true);
return redirect($response['paypal_link']);
```

tried to look for ams solutions so far nothing if someone can help me thank you

Answer (score 0):

may be due to mismatch of version.

try using this in **composer.json**

```
srmklive/paypal: "~1.0"
```